# list style type not displayed for li

Tags: css

I have two ol's. The list style type is displayed for the fist ol set. But for the second ol, its not shown. The first ol is static. But the li's for the second ol is displayed like hide and show..Can somebody please help me in this. This is the fiddle. The circle is coming only for the first ol but not for the second
http://jsfiddle.net/64ZNk/3/

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h4>1. One.</h4>
    </li>
</ol>
<ol id="help">
    <li>
        <h4>2. Two.</h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>3. Three.</h4>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
#help li {
    display: none;
}
#help li:first-child {
    display: block;
}
ol {
    list-style-type:circle;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) value for the `li` element should be `list-item`

```
#help li:first-child {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5w9Gc/)